# How can I upload an image and send it to my controller for validation and then save to my database?

Tags: php, laravel-5, vue.js

I am using Laravel 5.4 and Vue.js for the project. AddProduct.vue is my file that contains my form. Other form data except the image works fine. What should be my onchage method to upload the image and send it with other form data to my controller to process?

Here is my AddProduct.vue file

```
<template>
    <div class="">
        <form class="form-horizontal" @submit.prevent="onSubmit" @keydown="form.errors.clear($event.target.name)" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <!-- Product Image -->
                    <div :class="{ 'form-group': true, 'has-error': form.errors.has('product_image') }">
                        <label for="product_image" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                            Product Image
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="file"  @change="onFileChange" name="product_image" style="padding-top:7px;" aria-label="...">
                            <span v-if="form.errors.has('product_image')" class="help-block">
                                <strong v-text="form.errors.get('product_image')"></strong>
                            </span>
                        </div>      
                    </div>                  
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
                            <button :disabled="form.errors.any()" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6"></div>                
            </div>          
        </form>     
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        data() {
            return {
                form: new Form({
                    //other attributes
                    product_image: ''
                })
            }
        },

        methods: {
            onSubmit() {
                this.form
                .post('/product')
                .then(status => this.status());
            },
            onFileChange(e) {
            },

            status() {
                flash('Product added.');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is my controller code

```
public function store(StoreProduct $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'product_image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:1024',
        ]);
        if ($request->hasfile('product_image')){  
             if ($request->file('product_image')->isValid()) {
                 $image = $request->file('product_image');
                 $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                 $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
                 Image::make($image)->resize(400, 400)->save($location);        
            }               
        }
        $request->saveProduct();

        return back()->with('flash', 'Product has been added!');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onFileChange (e) {
  let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files
  if (!files.length) {
    return
  }
  this.createImage(files[0])
},
createImage (file) {
  var image = new Image()
  var reader = new FileReader()
  var vm = this
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    vm.image = e.target.result
    vm.$emit('imgUploaded', e.target.result)
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
```

Check the code above the code `e.target.result` is a base64 image data, and you can do pass this data to the server, and save it as an image.

The code is part of an image crop project of myself. You could check the source here: 
https://github.com/akulubala/vue-image-upload-croppie/blob/master/src/components/VueImageUploadCroppie.vue

Comment: Well that may upload the image. But how can I send it to my controller with other form data to process and save?? I am new to this and the concept is not clear to me.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon, if you want you can add a hidden input inside the form. let change event will assign the image data value to that hidden input

Comment: something like this? <input type="hidden" name="product_image" v-model="form.product_image">

Comment: @zahidhasanemon, yes

Comment: So what will be my final onchange method to upload the image and assign the image data value to my hidden input type?